# Cannot convert value of type 'Object' to expected argument type 'Object!'

Tags: objective-c, swift, casting

I'm working on rewriting an Objective-C project in Swift and I got stuck in a compiler error. I'm calling a method defined into a Objective-C protocol which has the signature:

```
- (void)startForBuilder:(Object*)builder;
```

and from Swift I'm calling this method like:

```
plugin.start(for: self)
```

where `self` is an instance of Object and plugin is an instance of an object which conforms to the protocol above. The error I'm getting is

`Cannot convert value of type 'Object' to expected argument type 'Object!'`

Replacing `self` with `self!` didn't work (because `self` is not an optional, obviously), I also tried to instantiate another object of the same type as `self` and use that instance as argument to check if the error disappears, but it's still there.

What could cause this error?

Comment: Try to declare the ObjC parameter explicitly as non-optional: `- (void)startForBuilder:(Object* _Nonnull *)builder;`

Comment: Tried that, now it says Cannot convert value of type 'Object' to expected argument type 'Object' / edit: I think that's because the `Object` class is now replaced with a Swift version and the code in the protocol still need an Objective-C class (to avoid a circular import I'm declaring the class in the protocol's interface file as `@class Object;`). I'll try to sort this out and I'll be back with an answer